# Compile errors when converting to Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

After a lot of attempts, I have not been able to successfully convert the following code to Kotlin. I get all kinds of compile errors no matter what I do. Can someone please convert this for me so that I can see what I am doing wrong:

```
Observable<Message> sendMessageObservable = networkClient.sendMessage(message);

sendMessageObservable.retryWhen(throwable -> {
    Observable<Long> retrySignal = throwable.zipWith(Observable.range(0, 6), (t, i) -> i)
                                            .flatMap(i -> { final long delay = (long) Math.pow(2, i);
                                                             return Observable.timer(delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                                                          }
                                                     );

    return retrySignal;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible for me to confirm a correct answer to your question because you reference a few values and therefore types that you don't define, and you give no info on what those values actually contain.  I'm not an Android developer.  Maybe if I was, I would know what the types of 'networkClient' and 'message' should be.  As it is, I made up some types and values that allowed me to compile your code in Java. I then converted it to Kotlin and got this equivalent code to compile:

```
val sendMessageObservable = networkClient.sendMessage(message)

sendMessageObservable!!.retryWhen { throwable ->
    val retrySignal = throwable.zipWith<Int, Int>(Observable.range(0, 6), BiFunction<Throwable, Int, Int> { _, i -> i})
            .flatMap { i ->
                val delay = Math.pow(2.0, i.toDouble()).toLong()
                Observable.timer(delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            }
    retrySignal
}
```

I'm not going to put together more guessing code to try to run this.  I hope this is worth something to you as is.